# Cannot copy files from a read-only data DVD

Tags: dvd, file-transfer, copy-protection

I have a data DVD that contains several little programs, videos and a bunch of presentations.
When I try copying something from this disc, I get an error message that looks like this:

[image]

I don't understand why I get this error while I'm trying to copy files and not move or delete them. Please help.

Comment: [Error Message - Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8gonx.png)

Comment: Just to confirm, are you copying, or moving? Also, can you try the disc in another drive?